# eclipse e4 menu item tooltip

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, eclipse-rcp, e4

How to use menu item tooltips? When I add a new menu item in fragment.e4xmi there is a "tooltip" text field in properties editor window, but when I run the application I see no tooltips. Should I do something tricky to enable them? I've seen on the Internet that it was an issue before, but I assume it should be already fixed since properties editor suggests me to enter a tooltip. Setting tooltip via setTooltip() method programmatically doesn't work either. I use Mars.1 Release (4.5.1).

Comment: What platform (Mac, Linux, Windows)? Is this the Main Menu, Context Menu, ...?

Comment: @greg-449 I use windows 7 64 bit. I tried to use it on handled and direct menu items (main menu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is Eclipse bug [473779](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=473779). Tool tips for menu items don't work in Eclipse 4.5.2 and earlier. This has been fixed in Eclipse Neon (4.6.0) due to be released shortly (June 2016).

I confirmed this testing on Mac OS X. Eclipse 4.5.2 doesn't show tool tips, Eclipse 4.6.0 does.